# Renaming Fastapi/Pydantic json output fields

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

As CamelCase is more idiomatic in json but underscores are more idiomatic in databases i wonder how to map someting like article_id (in database and hence the model) to articleId as the json output of fastapi/pydantic?
Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alias generator from Pydantic. [Here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/camel-case-models-with-fast-api-and-pydantic-5a8acb6c0eee) is a good article for it.